# R Linking outputs from DT & Leaflet packages

Tags: r, datatables, leaflet, dt

I am attempting to build an interactive dashboard using the `DT` and `leaflet` packages in R.  This dashboard will allow users to select specific filters from the table generated by the `DT` package and have the lat and long coordinates from the filtered table selection appear on the leaflet map.  Unfortunately I have no experience with javascript.

I can accomplish this task very easily using a `Shiny App`, however I am dealing with very sensitive data that cannot be passed outside a firewall which eliminates Shiny as an option.  Does anyone know of a way to link the output from the `DT` and `leaflet` packages?  Any job aids/tutorials you can steer me towards is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not a big fan of Shiny, but can't simply run Shiny server behind the firewall? How potential DT + leaflet solution differs? Ignoring that is probably to broad question for SO, not to mention that "_questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic_".

Comment: Not sure I can host a Shiny App on a windows PC without a Virtual Machine, and posting the app to shinyapps.io requires sending the data outside the firewall. DT+leaflet solution differs because all the data is stored in the html file and is never hosted offsite.

Comment: You can host shiny app with a server which is inside the firewall, no need to post the app to shinyapps.io. Check out http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/

Comment: For a small app you can use development server (the one you use when you call `shiny::runApp()`). If you want to use full featured server you can use a Docker container. As far as I know [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) works on Windows OS.

Comment: How about inlining a shiny app to a R Markdown document. From this you can generate a standalone .html file your users can run? http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html

Comment: You can also check out a company called Exaptive.com. The system is rugged to learn, but they offer full service too. You can create an R script and they create automated IDE apps that will integrate your processed data into a javscript front end that is interactive. It will work with leaflet too. If you need it they can create cached versions of the possible outcomes or you can run it on your own server behind a firewall once the application is live. We work with protected health information and are able to secure it well with their help. But it is not private person budget friendly.